# Snakemake with one input but multiple parameters permutations

Tags: python, parameters, workflow, wildcard, snakemake

I have been trying to wrap my head around this problem which probably has a very easy solution.
I am running a bioinformatics workflow where I have one file as input and I want to run a program on it. However I want that program to be run with multiple parameters. Let me explain.

I have `file.fastq` and I want to run `cutadapt` (in the shell) with two flags: `--trim` and `-e`. I want to run trim with values `--trim 0` and `--trim 5`. Also I want `-e` with values `-e 0.1` and `-e 0.5`

Thererfore I want to run the following:
`cutadapt file.fastq --trim0 -e0.5  --output ./outputs/trim0_error0.5/trimmed_file.fastq`
`cutadapt file.fastq --trim5 -e0.5  --output ./outputs/trim5_error0.5/trimmed_file.fastq`
`cutadapt file.fastq --trim0 -e0.1  --output ./outputs/trim0_error0.1/trimmed_file.fastq`
`cutadapt file.fastq --trim5 -e0.1  --output ./outputs/trim5_error0.1/trimmed_file.fastq`

I thought snakemake would be perfect for this. So far I tried:

```
E = [0.1, 0.5]
TRIM = [5, 0]

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        "file.fastq"

    output:
        expand("../outputs/trim{TRIM}_error{E}/trimmed_file.fastq", E=E, TRIM=TRIM)
    
    params:
        trim = TRIM,
        e = E

    shell:
        "cutadapt {input} -e{params.e} --trim{params.trim} --output {output}"
```

However  I get an error like  this:

```
shell:
cutadapt file.fastq -e0.1 0.5 --trim0 5 --output {output}
(one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

So, as you can see, snakemake is not taking each argument of the TRIM and E variables, but putting them together like a string. How could I solve this problem? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying `params`, right now you are providing full lists rather than specific values. Contrast the following parameter values:

```py
E = [0.1, 0.5]
TRIM = [5, 0]


rule all
    input: expand("../outputs/trim{TRIM}_error{E}/trimmed_file.fastq", E=E, TRIM=TRIM)

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        "file.fastq"
    output: "../outputs/trim{TRIM}_error{E}/trimmed_file.fastq"
    params:
       trim_list = TRIM,
       trim_value = lambda wildcards: wildcards.TRIM,
    shell:
       "cutadapt {input} -e{wildcards.E} --trim{wildcards.TRIM} --output {output}"
```

Note that in the `shell` directive there was no need to reference `params`, since this directive is aware of `wildcards`.

Comment: Hi, Than you for your response. I am realising that i don't understand snakemake's wildcards very well. In any case If I try your code the first wilcard.TRIM gives an error `wildcards object has no attribute TRIM`. Therefore wilcards are not aware of the environment?

Comment: The snippet I posted before was focussed only on a specific issue, I updated the answer to have a fuller code version. Note there are two rules now.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @SultanOrzbayev 's answer, The key was that I needed `rule all` with the parameters in order to use wildcards in my `rule cutadapt`.

The `parameters` section can actually be erased, so in the end:

```
E = [0.1, 0.5]
TRIM = [5, 0]


rule all
    input: expand("../outputs/trim{TRIM}_error{E}/trimmed_file.fastq", E=E, TRIM=TRIM)

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        "file.fastq"
    output: "../outputs/trim{TRIM}_error{E}/trimmed_file.fastq"
    shell:
       "cutadapt {input} -e{wildcards.E} --trim{wildcards.TRIM} --output {output}"
```